# IC socket on network cards?

Tags: networking, nic

I have been looking at network cards and I have noticed a few of them have this mysterious port on them that looks like an IC socket. I was wondering what this is used for and if it is of any significance when purchasing a new network card.

I am also curious about why there are two different socket types as well (square vs rectangle).

[image: Nic1]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite an old thing but as far as I know it's an optional boot ROM socket to allow the NIC to effectively PXE boot, though I think the actual protocol was proprietary. Most if not all modern NICs just have this ability by default rather than by option these days.